" Error processing Instruction 3: invalid account data for instruction" when trying to buy Solana token using Javascript
I'm building a bot using JavaScript to auto trade Solana token for me. It's coming along fine but when it's time for bot to buy, it's always logging this error for me:
Fetch Error: Simulation failed.
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 3: invalid account data for instruction.
Logs:
[
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]",
  "Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount3",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4188 of 122326 compute units",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
  "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 21845 of 139700 compute units",
  "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL success",
  "Program HWEHeKLzzwXix3wAT2HTNijeKChu9XERdqGid1UzzjPo invoke [1]",
  "Program HWEHeKLzzwXix3wAT2HTNijeKChu9XERdqGid1UzzjPo consumed 14236 of 117855 compute units",
  "Program HWEHeKLzzwXix3wAT2HTNijeKChu9XERdqGid1UzzjPo failed: invalid account data for instruction"
].
Catch the `SendTransactionError` and call `getLogs()` on it for full details.

Here is my code:
const web3Connection = new Connection(settingsObject.RPC, "confirmed");
async function buy(mint) {
    const response = await fetch(`${API}`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        publicKey: settingsObject.MASTER_PUBLIC_KEY,
        action: "buy",
        mint: mint,
        denominatedInSol: "true",
        amount: settingsObject.BUY_AMOUNT,
        slippage: 5,
        priorityFee: 0.00001,
        pool: "pump",
      }),
    });

    if (response.status === 200) {
      // successfully generated transaction
      const data = await response.arrayBuffer();
      const tx = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(new Uint8Array(data));
      const signerKeyPair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(
        bs58.decode(settingsObject.MASTER_PRIVATE_KEY)
      );
      tx.sign([signerKeyPair]);
      const signature = await web3Connection.sendTransaction(tx, {});

      return `Buy TX: https://solscan.io/tx/${signature}`;
    } else {
      console.log(response.statusText); // log error
    }
  }

Any suggestions to fix this? Thanks

could you share some info about the API you are using.

Hi, I'm using https://pumpportal.fun/
